# Undefined is returned even after making test

Tags: node.js, async.js

I made an `async parallel` :

```
async.parallel({
            ...,
            "dateDebut": function(cb_dateDebut) {
                request({
                            url: "https://alfred.telma.net/track_/trackable/dateDebut/".concat(req.body.donnee)
                        }, function (error, response, body) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(body);
                            var dataJSON = data[0];
                            var dateDebut = dataJSON.Date_debut;
                            var momentDateDebut = (dateDebut == "" ? null : moment(dateDebut, "DD-MM-YYYY, H:m:s"));
                            if (momentDateDebut == null)
                                cb_dateDebut("");
                            else
                                cb_dateDebut(momentDateDebut.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"));
                });
            }
        }, function(err, results) {
            var vehicule = results.vehicule, conducteur = results.conducteur, dateDebut = results.dateDebut;
            console.log("============ dateDebut : ",dateDebut);

            sheet1.cell(9, 1).string(vehicule.vehicule_nom);
            sheet1.cell(9, 2).string(vehicule.immatriculation);
            sheet1.cell(9, 3).string(conducteur);

            var tps = moment().format('YYYYMMDHHmmss')+moment().milliseconds();
            var nom_fichier = "reporting"+tps+".xlsx";
            wb.write(path.join(__dirname, '../public/pjreporting/'+nom_fichier));

            res.send("");
        });
```

At runtime I test when `dateDebut` equals to `""`. So in my test the wished result of `results.dateDebut` should be `""`. But in fact I get `undefined` ! So what is wrong ?

Comment: It seems that `results.dateDebut` in the last function is actually created somehow in the first function, but they run in parallel, which means the last function might be called before the first.

Comment: as by the doc of async , the last function is the callback of async ; so it is called when all functions are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error first!

Change your code:

```js
// cb_dateDebut("");
cb_dateDebut(null, "");
```